# How can i split each id into train and test

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, pandas-groupby

I want to split each id into 10% test and 90% train. I have variable count of each questionID and from each questionID i want to split in 10%test and 90% train.
I tried with groupBy but unfortunately i get not the correct output.

```
with open('CSSAG_for_SBERT.csv') as f:
df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t')
grouped = df.groupby('questionID')
train_set = []
test_set = []
for group in grouped:
    train, test = train_test_split(group, test_size=0.10, train_size=0.90)
    test_set.append(test)
    train_set.append(train)


print(test_set)
```

here you can see i firstly create groups by questionID. Then i want to split each id group into test and train data and sum up.What did i wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you assign `grouped` with `df.groupby('questionID')`, `grouped` is a list of tuple. The tuple element contains grouped key and associated subgroup. You might need

```py
for name, group in grouped:
    #^^ changes here
    train, test = train_test_split(group, test_size=0.10, train_size=0.90)
    test_set.append(test)
    train_set.append(train)
```